# .Net Chat Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, chat

i am developing chat application using vb.net and asp.net  where i am having a div tag inside which i am displaying the messages posted by the online users what my problem is when the messages are more and exceeds the height of the div tag then i am not comfortable to view the previous messages because i have set the scroll bar position to always to be pointed to bottom,

for clarity i have pasted my code please go through it and suggest your ideas

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="ChatContent" runat="server" style="height: 250px; vertical-align: top; overflow:auto; text-align: left; margin-left: 10px; width: 97%;">
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"UpdateMode="Conditional">  
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <textarea id="UserInputTextBox" cols="72" rows="3" runat="server" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13) Button2.click();" >
        </textarea> 
         <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Send" OnClick="Button2_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
         Sys.Application.add_load(function() { 
             var t = document.getElementById('ChatContent'); 
             t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight; 
         });
         </script>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks

Shakthi

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I went through it.  I suggest you clarify what the question is.

Comment: The messages inside the div tag when exceeds the hieght of the div tage ie, my div tags hieght is 250px if the messages exceeds this height then if i scroll to see the messages in top i cant view it because always my scroll position is at bottom so once i move the scrollbar to top it immediately comes to the bottom, i have kept the scroll bar to be always at bottom, then only the user can instantly see his messages i am expecting answers from experts

Answer (score 0):

When working with AJAX.NET you can use the `PageRequestManager` in JavaScript to monitor an AJAX callback being finished; specifically, it's `endRequest` event.

From what I can see, you haven't shown us your code for making sure the scrollbar is always at the bottom, but it seems from your comment that it constantly scrolls the div down, so I suggest you move the part of your code that scrolls the div down, from whatever `setInterval` you've been using, to the `endRequest`, and include a check in `endRequest` to see if the value has changed:

```
var contentLength = 0;

var requestMan = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
requestMan.add_endRequest(function() {

    // get a reference to your ChatContent div, by whatever means you prefer
    var container = document.getElementById( /* your ChatContent id */ );

    // this is fired at the end of a javascript callback
    // check if new posts were added in this callback

    if(content.innerHTML.length > contentLength) {

        // update this var, so that the same check won't evaluate to true at next callback
        contentLength = content.innerHTML.length;

        // scroll the div to its bottom, by whichever means you were doing it before
        content.scrollTop = 100000;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your input, I'll revise my answer, so that it uses your code, and requires as few changes as possible. What you've got there, is code that keeps scrolling down the DIV, and you want to change it so that it only scrolls the DIV if the content of the DIV has changed:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var contentLength = 0; // add this global var
     Sys.Application.add_load(function() { 
         var t = document.getElementById('ChatContent'); 

         if(t.innerHTML.length > contentLength) // <- add a condition here
             t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight; 
     });
     </script>
```

Just replace your script block with this, in your updatepanel, and you should be able to leave the rest as it is.

Comment: Thanks David Hedlund,
  your answer resembles to which i need,  i will post my code in next comment i have used code inside update panel when i click the send button the scrollbar will positions to bottom,


indeed i do know where to put your code to make the my scroll bar to move flexibly ,

i am really grateful for your help

regards

Shakthi

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate> 
<textarea id="UserInputTextBox" cols="72" rows="3" runat="server" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13) Button2.click();"  ></textarea>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Send" OnClick="Button2_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
var t = document.getElementById('ChatContent');
t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight;
});
</script>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

i dont know how to use your code

anyway thanks

Comment: alright, i put that code in your original post, so that it's easier to read, because i believe it is of interest for anyone trying to answer this. i've edited my own post to better answer your question

Comment: thanks for your effort david hedlund

even i replaced the code dosn't work for me

Comment: in that case i think you need to describe your problem better. please edit your question and elaborate. how's it currently working, and how do you want it to work?